# TensorFlow ParameterServerStrategy() not working for multi-gpu training

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, distributed

I'm following the tutorials on tensorflow 2.4.0: https://tensorflow.google.cn/tutorials/distribute/parameter_server_training
here is my code:

```
    # Parameter Server Training:https://tensorflow.google.cn/tutorials/distribute/parameter_server_training

import multiprocessing
import os
import random
import portpicker
import tensorflow as tf

# in-process cluster
def create_in_process_cluster(num_workers, num_ps):
    """Creates and starts local servers and return the cluster_resolver."""
    
    worker_ports = [portpicker.pick_unused_port() for _ in range(num_workers)]   
    ps_ports = [portpicker.pick_unused_port() for _ in range(num_ps)]

    cluster_dict = {}
    cluster_dict["worker"] = ["localhost:%s" % port for port in worker_ports]
    if num_ps > 0:
        cluster_dict["ps"] = ["localhost:%s" % port for port in ps_ports]

    cluster_spec = tf.train.ClusterSpec(cluster_dict)

    # workers need some inter_ops threads to work properly.
    worker_config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
    if multiprocessing.cpu_count() < num_workers + 1:
        worker_config.inter_op_parallelism_threads = num_workers + 1 
    
    for i in range(num_workers):
        tf.distribute.Server(
            cluster_spec,
            job_name="worker",
            task_index=i,
            config=worker_config,
            protocol="grpc")

    for i in range(num_ps):
        tf.distribute.Server(
            cluster_spec,
            job_name="ps",
            task_index=i,
            protocol="grpc")

    cluster_resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.SimpleClusterResolver(
        cluster_spec, rpc_layer="grpc")
    return cluster_resolver

# Set the environment variable to allow reporting worker and ps failure to the
# coordinator. This is a workaround and won't be necessary in the future.
os.environ["GRPC_FAIL_FAST"] = "use_caller"

NUM_WORKERS = 3
NUM_PS = 2
cluster_resolver = create_in_process_cluster(NUM_WORKERS, NUM_PS)


variable_partitioner = (
    tf.distribute.experimental.partitioners.MinSizePartitioner(
        min_shard_bytes=(256 << 10),
        max_shards=NUM_PS))


strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.ParameterServerStrategy(
    cluster_resolver,
    variable_partitioner=variable_partitioner)




def dataset_fn(input_context):
    global_batch_size = 64
    batch_size = input_context.get_per_replica_batch_size(global_batch_size)

   
    x = tf.random.uniform((10, 10))   
    y = tf.random.uniform((10, ))

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y)).shuffle(10).repeat()
    dataset = dataset(
        input_context.num_input_popelines,
        input_context.input_pipeline_id)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(2)

    return dataset


dc = tf.ketas.utils.experimental.DatasetCreator(dataset_fn)

with strategy.scope():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)])
    model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(), loss='mse', steps_per_execution=10)


working_dir = 'tmp/PST_working_dir'
log_dir = os.path.join(working_dir, 'log')
ckpt_filepath = os.path.join(working_dir, 'ckpt')
backup_dir = os.path.join(working_dir, 'backup')

callbacks = [
    tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir),
    tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=ckpt_filepath),
    tf.keras.callbacks.BackupAndRestore(backup_dir=backup_dir),
]

model.fit(dc, epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=20, callbacks=callbacks)
```

the error is:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't know whether is the problem of 'libcublas.so.11' or not because in the following information there shows 'successfully opened dynamic library licublas.so.11'. Here is the information of GPUs:

[image]

how can I solve this problem?